# Converting troublesome delimited PDF to Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, adobe, csv, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert [this delimited PDF](http://www.registrar.pitt.edu/Reports/tsch_fal/2111_TimeSchedule.pdf) to an excel (or some other delimited format).  Using Adobe Acrobat 9, I attempt to save it and copy it) as Excel but it gives the error message *"BAD PDF; error in processing fonts.  [348]"*.

I'm open to any solution that will create a delimited file, ranging from using Adobe Acrobat, to programming to using other apps.  The only limitation is that I don't have a budget to buy anything (such as Able2Extract).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to export my images and fonts without buying any extra software to do the conversion was this way. go to Advanced, PDG Optimizer, select all of the options you want on the LEFT COLUMN and where it says MAKE COMPATIBLE WITH select Acrobat 8.0 and later, OK....you are in your road to success

Answer (score 0):

Note: not really an answer, but some suggestions.

Sounds to me that Crystal Reports is not following the PDF spec close enough.

I'd make sure CR is fully updated/patched and try genning another file making sure that "tagging" is enabled - tagging defines the layout structure. I don't have a copy of CR handy, but you may have to define a distiller template to use so when you print to PDF you can select that job option.

You can also tell its a bad PDF by using Preflight in Acrobat, it says there is no tag structure and you can do it manually (draw boxes around each item...). Also that there is no language set, and it is somehow compatible with Acrobat 1.3? which isn't supported anymore and should be 4 at the lowest?

Once you have a "good" pdf can export to xml/word and import that to excel. Also, with Acrobat 8+ you can highlight using the select tool, right-click and choose Open As SpreadSheet. You might be able to get away with just highlighting the whole document -- though I'd hope the xml approach would be best.

Able2Extract does some OCRing and tricky fuzzy logic not only to define tags/layout so it is exportable, but also avoids any font, encoding, etc issue - at least to my knowledge.

In the rare case that you can't get a new file, then exporting to plain text/accessible seems to generate a nice flat text file. You could write a vbscript to parse it (adding your delimiter) and import that into excel.

Comment: I didn't create the report.  So it seems like retagging it is the only solution, then?

Comment: update.. my attempt at adding tags through Advanced->Accessiblity->Add tags to document did not work